# CNF H is in the class P

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

```
CNF H = {<ø>|ø is a satisfiable cnf-formula where each clause contains any number of 
literals, but at most one negated literal}
```

I want to show that CNF H is in P, but I'm having some trouble finding an algorithm. My first idea was to check for each clause c in P if that clause contained at most one negated literal. If no clause contains more than one negated literal, accept, if not, reject.

The problem with this idea is if there is a clause with only one literal, and this literal is negated. Than the clause would be false, and therefore ø is false. How do I write an algorithm that also covers this case?

Comment: The title suggests that you want to show that the problem is NP-complete, but in the text you say "in P", which are you trying? Why is a clause consisting of a single negated literal necessarily false? You can set the variable to false, then the literal evaluates to true (in fact, you have to if the formula is satisfiable).

Comment: Ah, saw the fault now, edited the title. Hm, that's true. But how do I give an algorithm for this? I can't seem to figure out a good method.

Comment: You should be able to find an answer to this yourself, armed with the knowledge that a clause with at most one *positive* literal is called a **Horn clause**. (The case with at most one negative literal is equivalent to swapping true and false.)

Comment: Hint: this is HORN-SAT in disguise. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability.

Comment: Okei, I think I got an algorithm! :) I edited my answer to include this algorithm, could you see if it is correct? Thank you for the tip of the horn clause.

Comment: @user2795095 We're not a homework checking service. You should be able to check your work yourself. If you are unsure about a *specific* point, you can ask about it.

Comment: Well, this is not homework. But I take your point, I just thought it would be nice to know if i got it right.

Comment: Your algorithm works, if you set `x` appropriately in step 3. It would be nice, if you could remove it from the question and add it as an answer, so that your question doesn't get listed as unanswered anymore. (You might also get additional feedback on your answer through votes or comments.)

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I have moved the algorithm to an answer :) Not quite sure what you mean by setting x appropriatly in step 3?

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a polynomial-time algorithm for this language that I think is in P.

Possible algorithm (-x means not x).

```
M = "on input <ø> where ø is a boolean formula in CNF:
1. Repeat until there are no (-x) unit clauses:
   For a unit clause (-x), remove all the clauses containing -x from ø
     and remove all occurrences of x from the clauses in ø
2. If there is an empty clause in ø, reject.
3. Let all literals x in ø be 1, -x 0, and accept.
```